# scalaz-stream: how to chunk with concatenation?

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

Is there an idiomatic way to chunk and concatenate?

The ways that I've found (examples for bytes):

  1.

```scala
import scodec.bits.ByteVector    

def byteChunk(n: Int): Process1[ByteVector, ByteVector] =
    process1.chunk(n).map(_.reduce(_ ++ _))
```

But the intermediate `Vector` (from `chunk`) isn't really needed in this case.

2. Based on copy/paste from process1.chunk:

```scala
def byteChunk(n: Int): Process1[ByteVector, ByteVector] = {

  def go(m: Int, acc: ByteVector): Process1[ByteVector, ByteVector] =
    if (m <= 0) {
      emit(acc) ++ go(n, ByteVector.empty)
    } else {
      def fallback = if (acc.nonEmpty) emit(acc) else halt
      receive1Or[ByteVector, ByteVector](fallback) { in =>
        go(m - 1, acc ++ in)
      }
    }

  go(n, ByteVector.empty)
}
```

Is there a way to do the same with combining the existing `Process`'es?

A side question: could `repeat` be used instead of `++ go`? Is this the same as the previous:

```scala
def byteChunk(n: Int): Process1[ByteVector, ByteVector] = {

  def go(m: Int, acc: ByteVector): Process1[ByteVector, ByteVector] =
    if (m <= 0) emit(acc)
    else ...

  go(n, ByteVector.empty).repeat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify this a bit using `take`, `last` and `scanMonoid`

```
def byteChunk(n: Int): Process1[ByteVector, ByteVector] = {
  process1.take[ByteVector](n).scanMonoid.last ++ Process.suspend(go(n))
}
```

(or replace `scanMonoid` with something like `.scan(ByteVector.empty)((acc, x: ByteVector) => acc ++ x)` if you do not wish to implement `Monoid[ByteVector]`).

It also appears that `Process.repeat` will work instead of `++ Process.suspend(go(n))` and the way `Process.repeat` is implemented suggests it will be true as long as `byteChunk(n)` is pure.